# How to find out the version of a specific shared library of OpenCV

Tags: linux, opencv

How to know the version of a specific shared library of `opencv`?

I only have shared libraries and a static library named `libopencv.a`. I am sure it's compiled by the sources of `opencv2` or `opencv3`. But I don't know which version. And there are no header files.

It's appreciated that if `nm` or `strings` or alike commands can achieve this goal.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @tink I have not installed it. The shared libraries of `opencv` are delivered to me as a necessary part for a binary program which runs on `Linux`.

Comment: call `getBuildInformation` on the shared object. that's an opencv function that returns a string of the entire cmake configuration step. -- so yes, `strings` will likely barf that up too. look for `General configuration for OpenCV` -- and if you can list some function names, that'd work too. APIs changed over time, so you can tell from what's there.

Comment: @ChristophRackwi "call `getBuildInformation` on the shared object." It ***seems impossible*** since there are no header files. If I have headers, it would be much easier, indeed.

Comment: with python's ctypes I can get a hold of arbitrary shared objects and call into them by function name, without headers. so that **is** possible. worst case, I need to adjust (know) the signature before calling. granted, getBuildInformation returns a `std::string` and I have no idea how that would work with ctypes. C++ is a headache.